# List down all container within a storage account of azure through databricks

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-databricks

I, want to dynamically get all storage account and containers within from an azure subscription by databricks. 
So, that I can go through each file within a container and get the files and their sizes which I have done earlier.
 Now I want to dynamically set my storage account and container to process within from my databricks environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per my experience and based on my understanding for  all operations in storage account with databricks, authentication is happening in azure storage account level . In that case , If you are trying to access storage account through service principal or storage account access key both are in storage account level , you can list out the containers within storage account .But we don't have option to list out the storage account within subscription . As workaround , you can use `powershell`, to get the storage accounts within subscription and pass those value for your logic.

You can use below code , to get the list of containers within storage account .

```
from azure.storage.blob.blockblobservice import BlockBlobService
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name='storageaccount', account_key='accesskey')
containers = blob_service.list_containers()
for c in containers:
    print(c.name)
```

Comment: Is there any way, I can call PowerShell by databrick to get storage accounts?

Comment: yes . even python SDK module is available . You can refer here . https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/storage-python-manage/storage-python-manage/